# Getting percentages from sql query and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm currently have a database that holds survey questions and am now wanting to run a special query but don't know how to do it. **Things to note:** There can be 2-6 answers per question depending on the question.

These are the tables I'm using and some example data:

```
 Table: answers_only         Table: questions_only
╔════════════════╦═══════════╗ ╔═════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ answer_ID (PK) ║ answer    ║ ║question_ID (PK) ║ question                   ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════╣ ╠═════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║    65114       ║ yes       ║ ║       123       ║ Are you happy?             ║
║    614         ║ no        ║ ║       1967      ║ You think you're smart?    ║
║    23          ║ sometimes ║ ╚═════════════════╩════════════════════════════╝      
╚════════════════╩═══════════╝

                    Table: questions
╔════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ unique_ID (PK) ║ question_ID (FK) ║ answer_ID (FK) ║ person_ID (FK) ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║              1 ║              123 ║          65114 ║           5521 ║
║              2 ║              123 ║          614   ║           2511 ║
║              3 ║             1967 ║          614   ║           2511 ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

So I have a table **questions** that contains IDs (FK) to **questions_only** which holds actual questions.

What I'm trying to get is the top percentage of a question and then order by this and get anything above 90% (query). So...let's say we had 100 people get asked about the 'are you happy?' question. 5% said **no** and 95% said **yes**. So because it's 95%, it'd show up in the query. On the other hand, if 20% answered **no** on the 'you think you're smart?' question and 80% said **yes** then it doesn't show up. I think I need to next a bunch of sub queries but I'm not sure. Here is what I have...but I know I'm way off. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT question, answer, round(COUNT(*)/(select count(*) from questions 
INNER JOIN questions_only on questions_only.question_ID=questions.question_ID)*100) AS    
'Percent' FROM questions 
INNER JOIN answers_only ON answers_only.answer_ID=questions.answer_ID 
INNER JOIN questions_only ON questions_only.question_ID=questions.question_ID 
GROUP BY answer order by COUNT(*) DESC
```

The end goal here is to find out all the questions that were easy answers, the majority is in favor of.

```
                         wanted results from query
╔═══════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ question                      ║      answer      ║      Percent   ║ 
╠═══════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬
║  Are you happy?               ║          Yes     ║          97    ║        
║  You think you're smart?      ║          Yes     ║          96    ║          
║  1-5 How exciting is surfing? ║            5     ║          92    ║          
╚═══════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Is sometimes counted as a yes or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a subquery with count of answers for each question and join it with your QUESTIONS table:

```
SELECT MAX(questions_only.question),
       MAX(answers_only.answer),
       (COUNT(*)/MAX(t.all_count))*100 as answer_percent


FROM questions
   JOIN ( 
           SELECT question_id, 
                  COUNT(*) as all_count
           FROM questions
           GROUP BY question_id 
         ) as t on questions.question_ID=t.question_ID
   JOIN questions_only ON questions.question_ID=questions_only.question_ID
   JOIN answers_only ON questions.answer_id=answers_only.answer_id

GROUP BY questions.question_ID,questions.answer_ID
HAVING (COUNT(*)/MAX(t.all_count))*100>=90
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db496/4)</kbd>

Comment: t.all_count will be not be visible inside the select and the query will not execute.

Comment: It's a bit like COUNT(*)/MAX() >= 0.9

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check this in studio, but it should give you a one of the ways to  do it.

```
select question, answer,  round((c/c1)*100) from 
   (select question, answer, count (*) c1, c from
      questions q 
      join questions_only qo on q.question_ID = qo.question_ID
      join answers a on q.answer_ID = a.answer_ID
      join (select question_ID, count(*) c fromquestions ) 
      as q1 on q.question_ID = q1.question_ID
      Group by question, answer) 
   as table
```